Windows Server running PowerBI is consuming too much CPU
I’m running PowerBI on a Windows Server which has:
4 CPUs
73GB RAM
It tends to have high CPU Load randomly, with its most consuming processes being:
ReportingServicesService.exe RSPowerBI.exe
msmdsrv.exe
I can’t find an specific reason for the server needing that much CPU for those processes I already checked the workloads and schedules, used Performance Monitor to check if there were bottlenecks, checked background processes and increase the RAM, but I can’t seem to find why the problem persists.

msmdsrv.exe is the Analysis Services database engine.  It's an in-memory semantic modeling engine, and is responsible for refreshing your Power BI models, and performing all the query processing for reports.
If it has high CPU utilization, it's because it's probably because of the number, size, or complexity of the Power BI semantic models you're running.

I’m running PowerBI on a Windows Server which has: 4 CPUs 73GB RAM

That's pretty small, if you're hosting semantic models and reports on a single server.
For larger deployments, you can run SQL Server Analysis Services in Tabular mode on stand-alone servers.
